# Setting the IAP pricing for a single region, different to every other region

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, in-app-purchase

I am creating an app with `IAPs` and I have everything working, including each region showing a price suited for that region. For example, US shows the price for the `IAP` on the `UIButton` in $ and £ in the UK.

I'm using two pricing tiers in my app with two `UIButtons`.

`UIButton` 1: Pricing Tier 1
`UIButton` 2: Pricing Alternative Tier 1

In every country, this works well because the first `UIButton` displays (for example, in the UK), £0.79 and the second displays £0.99 which is good.

The US however seems to have an issue. The pricing for the Tier 1 is $0.99 and the pricing for Alternative Tier 1 is also $0.99. Therefore, in my app, the UIButton 1 and 2 are showing $0.99 and $0.99 for both `IAPs`.

I'm not really sure I understand why there's this issue on the iTunes Pricing, but I'm thinking of doing some sort of check.

So in my app, I have:

```
- (NSArray *)iapUnlimitedEntriesPurchase
{
    if (!_iapUnlimitedEntriesPurchase)
    {
        _iapUnlimitedEntriesPurchase = @[@"com.companyname.App.Unlimited"];
    }
    return _iapUnlimitedEntriesPurchase;
}

- (void)validateProductIdentifiers
{    
    SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:self.iapUnlimitedEntriesPurchase]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

So would it be possible for me to check if I'm in the US locale (with a US account) and then return a different IAP non-consumable product that I'll create with a different pricing Tier?

So every other region would be normal, but if you're using a US account, then you'll be seeing a different pricing?

If this is possible, how and where would I put the code?

The reason I'm asking for this is because I could just use a different tier for the second `UIButton`, but then the price dramatically increases and that's higher than I ever wanted to go with my app.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory is that the alternative tiers were brought in to allow for prices that are based on "friendly" values of the local currency.  So there is a 0.99EUR tier instead of the 0.91EUR that 0.99US$ translates to.  They weren't added to allow for finer grain control over pricing.

While you could do what you want, it is a losing game.  As currency exchange rates fluctuate, the relative pricing of the two buttons will float if one is based on an alternative tier.  You could easily end up with the more valuable alternative costing less after a period of a few months.

Caveat: I don't use alternative tiers but the above is my understanding of them.

Comment: Thanks so much DrC - that's really helpful. I decided to remove the second IAP because essentially what my app was doing was: the user can add 10 entries for free, pay £0.79 for 100 entries and £0.99 for unlimited entries, but after speaking to Apple about this pricing, I've decided to just go with one IAP priced at £0.99. But your answer is really great - thanks so much for the information :)